# MS Word showing unwanted table borders on screen (but not on print preview)

Tags: microsoft-word

[solved myself, can't yet accept]

I have a MS Word document with a number of tables. The other day when I created it, the tables all had no borders. Today, I opened it up to find that the tables *did* have borders.

However, when I check the border properties on each table, it says that there are no borders. The tables are displayed with cell borders in all view modes except for the reading layout, and they do **not** show up on print preview.

As this document is going to generally be for on-screen viewing, I need to get rid of the borders. How can I accomplish this?

(this is a MS Word 2003 *.doc document, in MS Word 2003, which has been the only editor involved.)

Comment: Could you post a screen shot? I think that might help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah! Table->Show Gridlines!

</facepalm>

Comment: I'll leave the question of how that got selected to the ages.